# How to know if the last closed activity was the last activity in the stack in Android?

Tags: android

I want to unbind/disconnect/shutdown/destroy my Service (same process) when the last activity in the stack is closed (for ex: pressing back key will close the current activity and you'll see Android home screen)

How can I know if user FULLY left my application and not just an activity? Is it also possible to catch if user pressed home button? (I know I can catch onPause/onStop of activities but user may be switching from one activity to another.. similar to my first/main question)

Answer (score 1):

Maintain the activity stack of your application. You can achieve this by many ways:

1. If your application has multiple entry points, then you can track which activities your user has opened and where they currently are, and accordingly when the the stack is pushing out its last item, pop the service.
2. If your app doesn't have multiple entry points, then you can just monitor the onStop of your Launcher activity.
3. If you want to also stop your service while multi-tasking, you'll have to be more creative with intents and sending a few flags as payloads. Maybe stop the service onStop if a flag isn't set by starting another one of your activities.

Answer (score 0):

This could be useful: `boolean Activity.isTaskRoot()`

According to the docs, `this method returns whether this activity is the root of a task. The root is the first activity in a task.`

Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isTaskRoot%28%29).

Comment: that would give the spawning root of the task if the activity is spawned from another application without the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK